# VB.NET load Datagridview thrown exception while calling it from different thread

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, datagridview

Firstly sorry for my bad English.

My problem is when I'm load data from different thread cause "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Here is my code :

```
Private Sub GetData(ByVal startRecord As Integer, ByVal maxRecord As Integer)

    Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet()
    Dim da As MySqlDataAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter("select * from my_data", SqlCon)

    Try
        da.Fill(ds, startRecord, maxRecord, "my_data")
        ds.Tables("my_data").DefaultView.AllowNew = False
        dgv.DataSource = ds.Tables("my_data")

        For Each col As Object In dgv.Columns
            If TypeOf col Is DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn Then
                DirectCast(col, DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn).Visible = False
            ElseIf TypeOf col Is DataGridViewImageColumn Then
                DirectCast(col, DataGridViewImageColumn).Visible = False
            ElseIf TypeOf col Is DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Then

                Dim tbc As DataGridViewTextBoxColumn = CType(col, DataGridViewTextBoxColumn)
                If tbc.Name = "no" Then
                    tbc.Width = 40
                    tbc.DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
                    tbc.HeaderText = "No"
                ElseIf tbc.Name = "ID" Then
                    tbc.Width = 110
                    tbc.HeaderText = "ID"
                ElseIf tbc.Name = "name" Then
                    tbc.Width = 290
                    tbc.HeaderText = "Name"
                ElseIf tbc.Name = "Address" Then
                    tbc.Width = 230
                    tbc.HeaderText = "Address"
                Else
                    tbc.Visible = False
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```

The problem is here :

```
dgv.DataSource = ds.Tables("my_data")
```

So, what's wrong with my codes? It's always getting error when calling it from multithreading method, but when i put in on the button it's work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It's always getting error when calling it from multithreading method,
>   but when i put in on the button it's work fine.

Your GetData() method is obviously not located in your Form, so it has no idea who "dgv" is.  One solution would be to pass the DataGridView just like your other parameters.

Change:

```
Private Sub GetData(ByVal startRecord As Integer, ByVal maxRecord As Integer)
```

To:

```
Private Sub GetData(ByVal dgv As DataGridView, ByVal startRecord As Integer, ByVal maxRecord As Integer)
```

Then the call (in your Form) would look like this:

```
GetData(dgv, someValue, someOtherValue)
```

Answer (score 0):

what vb is saying to you is that the variable you are trying to use hasn't nothing in it. you need to set it to point at something.

no where in your code have you specified what `dvg` is and you haven't carried the `dvg` over into the subroutine.

so you should have `dim dvg as something = something` or `dim dvg as new something = new something`

Comment: Thank you for your reply but now my datagridview does not load anything when i put `Dim dgv As DataGridView = New DataGridView`